# Testing if a 4-regular graph can be decomposed into two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

Given a 4-regular graph, is it NP-complete to test whether it can be decomposed into two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X8490101X for the directed case.